# dynamic js and jquery conflits

Tags: jquery

We have a HTML template which is shared by many application. Now we have to implement some js from a vendor, we are asked to put a js reference right after the body tag, and that js actually use  document.getElementsByTagName('script') and insertBefore method to dynamically inject some js right after head tag, so the final html looks like this:

```
<head>
    <script> A </script>
    <script> B </script>

<body>
    <script> first </script>
```

Question, as script A/B is using jQuery, and since this is a template html, the application using this template might have some other different jquery loading, how should I avoid the conflits? I know we should use $.noConflit Method, but I am not sure how to do this.

we are not allowed to change the first/A/B script, so I assume we should keep '$/jquery' for these guys. and I also want to make sure those jQuery loaded by each app can still use $

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, the following was written under the assumption that A/B were internal/"yours". Since this is not the case, the latter doesn't strictly apply - good luck!

---

To write code that is well-isolated from other code (i.e. independent of `$` or `jQuery` from elsewhere), use the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

A simple form looks like:

```
;(function ($) {           // Dependencies bound here (in parameters)
    // Rest of your code;
    // you can be assured that $ is for "your" jQuery
    // because it was bound/injected when the script was executed.
})(jQuery.noConflict())    // Dependencies injected here - immediately.
```

This makes it easy(ier) to isolate dependencies and "bind" to a specific object - in this case, `jQuery` can be reassigned after this script is run and it won't make a difference because the correct jQuery object has already been bound. This is also easily convertible to [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) (or a different module loader) if ever desired.

Just make sure "your" version of jQuery is loaded before the A/B scripts and "their" version (if required) is loaded before the C script. Remember that script element execution is synchronous by default.

```
<head>
    <script src="YourVersionOfJQuery"> </script>
    <script> A </script>
    <script> B </script>

<body>
    <script src="TheirDependenciesAndMaybeOldjQueryVersion"> </script>
    <script> /* other setup as required */ </script>
    <script> C </script>
```

You may have to "play" with different orderings.

Comment: sorry, how do I add a line break in the comments?

Comment: @Zhongmin Can't :) Use backticks-for-code-or-markup and semicolons or `\n` to show line-break intent.

Comment: <head>
    <script src="YourVersionOfJQuery"> </script>
    <script> A </script>
    <script> B </script>

    <script src="another version jquery"> </script>
    <script> /* other setup as required */ </script>
    <script> C </script>  </head>,     this way I don't need to call no conflits method?  I have all the js in head section.